# USB device shown in lsusb but not appearing in /dev/tty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

This device works fine on windows, while on Ubuntu 16.04 I can see it only in the connected devices list but no /dev/tty* ports are instantiated, making it impossible to access it.

The `lsusb -v` output regarding that device is the following:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0483:5750 STMicroelectronics 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0483 STMicroelectronics
  idProduct          0x5750 
  bcdDevice            2.01
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              300mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      33
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               2
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               2
```

Is there any way to associate it to a usb port?

EDIT: The mentioned device is a programmable servo controller. I should send commands to it through serial communication, that's why I would like to have it mapped on a /dev/tty*-like port.

EDIT #2: I have added the rule in udev, still I can't access the device properly. Here I provide the related output from the /var/log/syslog:

```
Jan 30 13:10:02 cr055 kernel: [  615.391231] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Jan 30 13:10:03 cr055 kernel: [  615.540602] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5750
Jan 30 13:10:03 cr055 kernel: [  615.540605] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 30 13:10:03 cr055 kernel: [  615.540607] usb 3-1: Product: LOBOT
Jan 30 13:10:03 cr055 kernel: [  615.540609] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: MyUSB_HID
Jan 30 13:10:03 cr055 kernel: [  615.540610] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 498F248E3033
Jan 30 13:10:03 cr055 kernel: [  615.541725] hid-generic 0003:0483:5750.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [MyUSB_HID LOBOT] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
Jan 30 13:10:03 cr055 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Jan 30 13:10:03 cr055 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 10 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: What is the device? I guess it's some kind of microprocessor, but I'd prefer _you_ to tell _us_.

Comment: it's a programmable servo controller, so yes, basically a microprocessor

Answer (score -1):

You modify UDEV info to assign a tty to the device when it is plugged in.  Something similar to the below might be appropriate

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="483", ATTRS{serial}=="00492F60", SYMLINK+="ttyS99"
```

You would add this to a file (which starts with a number- and ends .rules) in /etc/udev/rules.d - eg /etc/cudev/rules.d/20-microontroller.rules

You would then need to restart udev.

BTW, its generally a good idea to provide the log output generated in /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog when you plug a device in.

Comment: The rule has been added, but still doesn't work. I have edited the question in order to add the /var/log/syslog output